# What is the terminology used for equations that don't have the same tensor rank (order) on the LH and RH sides of the equation?

Tags: terminology

For example, in physics, if the dimensions of the term on the LHS of an equality do not match the dimensions of the RHS we say the equality is not dimensionally consistent.

So, what do we say for equalities that do not have the same tensor rank (order) on the LH and RH sides of the equation, e.g., if the term on the LHS is a scalar (rank 0 tensor) and the term on the RHS is a vector (rank 1 tensor)?

In the context of dimensional consistency, we say the equality is "dimensionally consistent" if the equality is correct (w.r.t. dimensions), or we say the equality is "dimensionally inconsistent" if someone did something wrong. This is terminology that exists. It goes beyond just saying, "you did something wrong", and identifies what is wrong (the dimensions are not consistent).

So I wonder if there is something analogous for when the tensorial rank of an equality is not consistent.

Comment: I think the term would still be "dimensionally inconsistent", refering to the dimensions of a matrix.